# Using Pivot or CTE to horizontalize a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using sql 2008
My data set looks like

```
Entity    Type1    Type2    Balance 
1         A        R        100
1         B        Z        200
1         C        R        300
2         A        X        1000
2         B        Y        2000
```

My output should look like

```
Entity  A-Type2 A-Balance B-Type2 B-Balance C-Type2 C-Balance 
1       R       100       Z       200       R       300
2       X       1000      Y       2000              0
```

Now I started writing a pivot query, and I think I can get away with MAX because there should be one record per Entity/Type1 combination.   But can not figure out how to do two fields in one pivot.  Is this possible?  Is this something that CTE could help out with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest is the MAX idea, but with a CASE statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  Entity,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type1 = 'A' THEN Type2 ELSE NULL END) AS AType2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type1 = 'A' THEN Balance ELSE NULL END) AS ABalance,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type1 = 'B' THEN Type2 ELSE NULL END) AS BType2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type1 = 'B' THEN Balance ELSE NULL END) AS BBalance,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type1 = 'C' THEN Type2 ELSE NULL END) AS CType2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type1 = 'C' THEN Balance ELSE NULL END) AS CBalance
FROM
  ...
GROUP BY
  Entity
```

In other words, only use the value when Type1 is a specific value (with other Type1 values getting a null).

Answer (score 3):

You just use conditional aggregation for the pivoting like this:

```
select Entity,
       max(case when Type1 = 'A' then Type2 end) as A_Type2,
       max(case when Type1 = 'A' then Balance else 0 end) as A_Balance,
       max(case when Type1 = 'B' then Type2 end) as B_Type2,
       max(case when Type1 = 'B' then Balance else 0 end) as B_Balance,
       max(case when Type1 = 'C' then Type2 end) as C_Type2,
       max(case when Type1 = 'C' then Balance else 0 end) as C_Balance
from MyDataSet mds
group by Entity;
```

Comment: Sorry I can only mark one answer correct even though the two answers are identical.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Mike . . . No problem.  Troy was 57 seconds faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's doing it with a pivot and a lookup.

```
SELECT 
data.Entity, 
ISNULL(a.Type2,'') AS [A-Type2], 
ISNULL([A-Balance],0) AS [A-Balance], 
ISNULL(b.Type2,'') AS [B-Type2], 
ISNULL([B-Balance],0) AS [B-Balance], 
ISNULL(c.Type2,'') AS [C-Type2], 
ISNULL([C-Balance],0) AS [C-Balance] 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    Entity, 
    A AS [A-Balance], 
    B AS [B-Balance], 
    C AS [C-Balance] 
FROM
(
SELECT Entity, Type1, Balance FROM @table
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(Balance)
    FOR Type1 IN ([A],[B],[C])
) piv
) data
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table a on a.Type1 = 'A' 
AND a.Entity = data.Entity AND a.Balance = [A-Balance] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table b on b.Type1 = 'B' 
AND b.Entity = data.Entity AND b.Balance = [B-Balance] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table c on c.Type1 = 'C' 
AND c.Entity = data.Entity AND c.Balance = [C-Balance]
```

Comment: That is creative, but the solutions above work well enough.  Thank you for the effort.